# how to create JQuery custom functions with Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have question that how to create custom functions in jQuery

I have a difficult situation here,

```
var value1= [];
var value2= [];
var value3= [];


function functionName(first,second,three,four = [])  {
}

$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    // 1 st way 
    functionName(value1,value2,value3);
    // 2nd way 
    functionName(value1,value2,value3,value4);

});
```

Can i use like this ? 
I mean my function 'functionName' has 4 parameters but some cases it has only 3 parameter so in that case I want last parameter should consider as empty.

so I can use like this in JQuery ?
I am using Codeception Test cases but if I use four = [] its getting fail.

Comment: I don't see what jQuery has to do with this. but, yes, it's certainly possible to create a function that accepts a variable number of arguments.

Comment: I am just confirming @kevin

Comment: another way to do that would be to use the arguments object. in other words create your function with no parameters, then inside the function use something like for(var I = 0; I < arguments.length; i++){}. That way you should be able to pass in any number of arguments and not have to set a default value for the last param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this . It is much to do with javascript rather than jQuery

check this snippet

```js
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a*b;
}

console.log(multiply(5));
console.log(multiply(5,8));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just to be clear though, the `b = 1` portion [doesn't work in all browsers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: @greeky its possible.. Thanks... Then It may be problem with Codeception Testing Library.. I will check with them

Comment: @TumuDinakar ...As kevin pointed out there are some broswer issues with this code...do check for the browser compatability and then use it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the arguments object so you can have different number of arguments

```
function foo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```